# Python Django - Customizing add user save method

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am pretty new to django framework . I am working on add user form in admin login .I need to send user details to third party API , On success from API call ,have to save in application database . Could you please guide me how to customize user save method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you override `clean()` method in UserCreationForm. This way, you can send user details to third party API and validate it.

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
    def clean(self):
        # Send API

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

[clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

[custom user creation form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion . I implemented in that way but api is calling if the form is not valid also . I have to Call API only if form is valid. I tried but not able to sort that.

Comment: The ``clean()`` method is called after form fields ``clean_fieldname()`` methods is called, it means the form is validated.